# Error, core data, reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

Hi i am almost new in programing.
I am faced with an error that I couldn't solve anyway. Even after comparing with anther solutions.
I have worked on it for about 3 days.

So let me completely describe my problem:

1.this is my implementation code:

```
#import "DocumentTableViewController.h"
#import "AddDocumentTableView.h"
#import "DB_document.h"

@implementation DocumentTableViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize btnAddDocument;
@synthesize fetchedObjects;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DB_document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%d",[fetchedObjects count]);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setBtnAddDocument:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int result = 0;
    if (section == 0) 
    {
        result = [fetchedObjects count] + 1;
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    DB_document *db_document = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        UILabel *lblMoney = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 40)];
        lblMoney.text = @"amount";
        lblMoney.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblMoney.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblMoney.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblMoney.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblMoney];

        UILabel *lblDescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 0, 150, 40)];
        lblDescription.text = @"description";
        lblDescription.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblDescription.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblDescription];

        UILabel *lblDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 70, 40)];
        lblDate.text = @"date";
        lblDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblDate];

        UIButton *btnLine1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnLine1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 1, 40);
        [cell addSubview:btnLine1];

        UIButton *btnLine2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnLine2.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 1, 40);
        [cell addSubview:btnLine2];

        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row != 0)
    {
        UILabel *lblMoney = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 40)];
        lblMoney.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",db_document.docAmount];
        lblMoney.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblMoney.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblMoney.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblMoney.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblMoney];

        UILabel *lblDescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 0, 150, 40)];
        lblDescription.text = db_document.docDescription;
        lblDescription.numberOfLines = 2;
        lblDescription.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblDescription.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblDescription];

        UILabel *lblDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 70, 40)];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd"];
        lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormater stringFromDate:(NSDate *)db_document.docDate]];
        lblDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblDate];

        UIButton *btnLine1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnLine1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 1, 40);
        [cell addSubview:btnLine1];

        UIButton *btnLine2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnLine2.frame = CGRectMake(240, 0, 1, 40);
        [cell addSubview:btnLine2];

        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        UILabel *lblMoney = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 40)];
        lblMoney.text = @"";
        lblMoney.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblMoney.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblMoney.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblMoney.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblMoney];

        UILabel *lblTotalAmount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 0, 140, 40)];
        lblTotalAmount.text = @"amounts";
        lblTotalAmount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblTotalAmount.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblTotalAmount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTotalAmount.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell addSubview:lblTotalAmount];

        UIButton *btnLine = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnLine.frame = CGRectMake(160, 0, 1, 40);
        [cell addSubview:btnLine];

        return cell;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)btnAddDocument_click:(id)sender
{
    AddDocumentTableView *addDocumentTableView = [[AddDocumentTableView alloc] init];
    addDocumentTableView.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addDocumentTableView animated:YES];
}
```

2.this is the error:

2012-06-16 15:25:31.696 Account5[5534:fb03] 2
2012-06-16 15:25:31.704 Account5[5534:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'
*** First throw call stack:

3.Let me describe the program. I can save data to data base with core data but when i want to fetch the data program jumps out.I have to consider that I think NSManagedObjectContext fetched data  because fetchedObjects Array has 2 data because I inserted in.
and I have to say that my RootViewController is DocumentTableViewController it means that exactly when I run the program it crashes. And if I want to run the app I must comment `DB_document *db_document = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

and after that app runs and I can insert data in another page.
I have to consider that when the app crashes it stops exactly on

`DB_document *db_document = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

with green highlighted line.
thank you

Comment: You are posting way too much code. Please select the section of your code that you think is responsible and delete the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your problem:

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you add one to the `fetchedResults` array. Presumably, you want to add an additional row in that section. That is fine.

However, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you take `indexPath.row` as the index for your `db_document`. Obviously, in the last row it will crash. You have to first check in which row you are and then retrieve your `db_document` only if you need it for that particular row.

Comment: thank you friend.
i was completely confused.
again, thanks for spending time.
you have just made me free. :))

Comment: i have deleted +1 from my code in [numberOfRowsInSection] but it doesn't solve my problem completely.
my table has shortage of a row !!!
it means if i have 3 data my table will show 2 data (actually as you said i want to add an additional row bot i don't know how?)

Comment: Keep the +1 and check for which row you are in in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Only query your array when you are sure the index is not beyond the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

```
result = [fetchedObjects count] + 1;
```

on numberOfRowsInSection 
you add one row more than fetchedObjects count and when you on the cellForRowAtIndexPath
the fetchedObjects has for example 3 row and you get row 4 ,and this exception occored and you get out of range on this array.